# Necessary conditions for convergence of convolution

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, limits-and-convergence, laplace-transform

In math.SE, I've asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4842092/product-of-laplace-transforms-with-disjoint-region-of-convergence-roc) about the convergence of convolution of two functions which have bilateral Laplace transform and also have disjoint Region Of Convergence (ROC) but the question didn't receive a rigorous answer. I think the main reason is that there are no general necessary conditions for convergence of convolution. There are many sufficient conditions but I couldn't find any necessary conditions. Note that by convolution I mean the Riemann improper integral $$y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau. \tag{1}$$ Is there any necessary conditions for convergence of $(1)$? Specifically, I'm looking for conditions which help me to show that the disjointness of ROCs leads to divergence of convolution.

**Edit:** Note that by convergence of convolution I mean that $(1)$ converges for almost all $t\in \mathbb{R}$. Willie Wong's shows that it's possible to construct an example such that $\text{ROC}_1 = \text{ROC}_2 = \text{ROC}_1 \cap \text{ROC}_2 = \emptyset$ and $(1)$ converges for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ but I actually wanted that $\text{ROC}_1 \not = \emptyset$ and $\text{ROC}_2 \not = \emptyset$.

Comment: Do you have any assumption on $x$ and $h$ ?

Comment: @PietroMajer Yes. The assumptions are, $$X(s) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x(t)\exp(-st)dt \ \ \ \  \text{converges for} \ s \in \text{ROC}_1 \\ H(s) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h(t)\exp(-st)dt  \ \ \ \  \text{converges for} \ s \in \text{ROC}_2 \\ \text{ROC}_1 \cap \text{ROC}_2 = \emptyset.$$

Comment: There cannot be an answer in the level of generality you are looking at. Let $\chi(t)$ be equal to $1$ if $t \in [n-0.1,n+0.1]$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0$ otherwise, and set $x$ and $h$ to be both equal to $\chi$. Then the Laplace transform for neither $x$ nor $h$ converge, and hence $ROC_1 = ROC_2 = \emptyset$. But their convolution converges for lots of $t$, as for many values the function $\tau \mapsto x(\tau) h(t-\tau)$ is identically $0$. // Right now I am not sure what you mean by "the convolution converges", do you mean the integral converges for all $t$ or for one $t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, here's a very strong counterexample (to the idea that disjoint ROCs lead to divergent convolutions), riffing off [of my earlier comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463154/necessary-conditions-for-convergence-of-convolution#comment1202920_463154).

Let $S = \{ (-2)^k : k \in \mathbb{N} \}$. Choose $0 < \epsilon \ll 1$. Set
$$\chi(t) = \begin{cases}
1 & \exists s\in S, \quad |t-s| < \epsilon \\
0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Set $x = h = \chi$. I claim that $\int \chi(t) \exp(-st) ~dt$ converges for no $s\in \mathbb{C}$, and hence $ROC_1 = ROC_2 = \emptyset$.

---

**Proof of claim**

For $s = 0$ the claim is obvious. So consider $s \neq 0$.

The integral can be formally computed, as $\chi$ is a characteristic function of intervals of length $2\epsilon$. We find

$$ \begin{multline*}
\int \chi(t) \exp(-st) ~dt = \\
\sum \frac{\exp(-s ((-2)^k - \epsilon))- \exp(-s ((-2)^k + \epsilon))}{s} = \\
\left( \sum \exp(-s (-2)^k)\right) \left( \frac{\exp(s\epsilon) - \exp(-s\epsilon)}{s} \right)\end{multline*} $$

One can see that a necessary condition for the integral to converge is the convergence of the infinite sum $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \exp(-s (-2)^k)$. This sum diverges for the simple reason that, for any $s \in \mathbb{C}$, the limit $\lim_{k\to\infty} \exp(-s(-2)^k) \neq 0$. (When the real part of $s$ is non-zero, the modulus has $\limsup |\exp(-s(-2)^k))| = + \infty$; when the real part of $s$ is zero, you have $|\exp(-s(-2)^k)| = 1$.) The claim follows.

---

Now, consider the function $g(\sigma,\tau) = x(\sigma) h(\tau)$. This function is non-zero if and only if $\sigma$ is approximately an element of $S$, and $\tau$ is approximately an element of $S$. Let us look at the value of $\sigma+\tau$ when this happens. We have necessarily that there exists $k,l\in\mathbb{N}$ such that

$$ \sigma + \tau \approx (-2)^k + (-2)^l = (-2)^l [ 1 + (-2)^{k-l} ] $$

Observe the following fact:

> $(-2)^k + (-2)^l = (-2)^m + (-2)^n$ if and only if either $\{k,\ell\} = \{m,n\}$ or $k = \ell = \min(m,n) - 1 = \max(m,n) - 2$ or vice versa.

A consequence of this is that for any fixed $t$, the function  $g(\tau,t-\tau)$ has compact support.

As a consequence: the integral defining the convolution $x*h$ is well-defined for every $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

---

The OP requested a bit more detail on how to prove the quoted fact and how to use it.

**Proof of fact**

WLOG assume $k \geq l$ and $m \geq n$. Then we have

$$ (-2)^l [ 1 + (-2)^{k-l}] = (-2)^n [1 + (-2)^{m-n}] $$

When $k-l \geq 1$, the number $[1 + (-2)^{k-l}]$ is odd and not divisible by 2. Hence we find first that

- If $k-l\geq 1$ and $m-n\geq 1$, by unique factorization we have $l = n$, and hence $k-l = m-n$.

It remains to consider the case where at least one of the pair are the same. So assume that $k = l$. Then

$$ 2(-2)^k = (-2)^{n}[1 +  (-2)^{m-n}] $$

Divide into cases:

- If $m = n$ then necessarily $m = n = k$
- If $m \geq n + 2$ we see that the RHS is divisible by an odd integer $\geq 3$, but not the LHS, so that is impossible.
- If $m = n + 1$, we find
  $$ 2(-2)^k = (-2)^{n}[-1] \implies n = k + 1 $$

**How to use this fact**

We are interested in those points for which $g(\tau,t-\tau) \neq 0$ for $t$ fixed. Let $T = \{ (-2)^k + (-2)^l: k,l\in \mathbb{N} \}$. Then we already agreed that $g(\tau,t-\tau) = 0$ whenever $\mathrm{dist}(t, T) > 2 \epsilon$.

So now take $t$ to be within $2\epsilon$ of $T$, and assume $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small that only one element of $T$ is selected, and suppose this element can be written as $(-2)^{k_0} + (-2)^{l_0}$.

By our "fact", this element of $T$ has at most **three** representations as $(-2)^k + (-2)^l$.

- If $|k_0 - l_0| > 1$, then our fact implies that the only possibilities are $k = k_0$ and $l = l_0$, or $k=l_0$ and $l = k_0$.
- If $k_0 = l_0 + 1$, then our fact implies that the only possibilities are $(k,l) \in \{(k_0,l_0), (l_0, k_0), (l_0 - 1,l_0-1)\}$. Similarly if $l_0 = k_0 + 1$.
- If $k_0 = l_0$, then our fact implies the only possibilities are $(k,l)\in \{(k_0,l_0), (k_0 + 1, k_0 + 2), (k_0 + 2, k_0 + 1)\}$.

In particular, for $t \approx (-2)^{k_0} + (-2)^{\ell_0}$, the only possibility for $g(\tau, t-\tau) \neq 0$ is if $\tau \approx (-2)^k$ and $(t-\tau) \approx 2^{l}$ for one of the $(k,l)$ pairs listed above. (Here $\approx$ is within, say, $4\epsilon$.) This is enough to proof the claim that for each fixed $t$, the set of $\tau$ such that $g(\tau,t-\tau) \neq 0$ is a bounded set.

If you want a quantitative bound, you have that $2^{\max(k_0,l_0)} \leq 4 |t|$, and the admissible $k$s are all $\leq \max(k_0,l_0) + 2$, so a very rough estimate is that
$$ \{\tau: g(\tau,t-\tau) \neq 0 \} \subseteq \{\tau: |\tau| \leq 16 |t| \} $$

---

It is not clear to me what would be a "reasonable" hypothesis to rule out this kind of cancellations. Certainly a sufficient condition to rule this out would be to require that $x$ and $h$ be monotonic outside a compact set, but this feels too strong an assumption to make.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I clarified my question, sorry for being inaccurate. Is it possible construct an example for the case $\text{ROC}_1 \not = \emptyset$ and $\text{ROC}_2 \not = \emptyset$?

Comment: @S.H.W. just set $x(t) = e^{-\eta |t|} \chi(t)$ and $h(t) = e^{-\eta|t| + 5 \eta t}\chi(t)$. Then $ROC_1 =(-\eta,\eta)$ and $ROC_2 = (-6\eta,-4\eta)$. Since the support properties of $x$ and $h$ are unchanged, you still have $x*h$ is well defined for every $t$.

Comment: The way to think about it is: in order to make the laplace transform converge (for some $s$), you will need to make $x$ and $h$ have **better** "decay properties", but such improvement can only help the integral defining $x*h$ converge, so the case $ROC_1 = ROC_2 = \emptyset$ should be the "hardest" case when it comes to counterexamples.

Comment: I see, thanks. Do you know any famous function space in which the result holds? In fact this question comes from signal processing in which many functions belong to $L^1$ or $L^2$.

Comment: If a function is in $L^1$, then $0$ belongs to its ROC, so the disjoint condition cannot happen for two $L^1$ functions. // For the $L^2$ case, you can add a mild decay to $\chi$: set it to be $\chi(t) = k^{-2/3}$ when $|t - (-2)^{k}| < \epsilon$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $\chi(t)$ is in $L^2$, but its ROC is empty. This $\chi$ shows that the claimed statement cannot hold for $L^2$ functions. // Finally, the paragraph I included below the horizontal bar was intended to address your question about "famous function space", with the answer of "I don't know."

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry that I'm asking again but there are some confusions that I couldn't resolve. (1) What $\epsilon $ actually is needed for this argument? I mean what's the precise characterization of $\epsilon \ll 1$ here. (2) We define the Laplace transform for $s \in \mathbb{C}$. Obviously $\int \chi(t) \exp(-st) ~dt$ converges for no $s \in \mathbb{R}$ but what about $s \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: (3) How the mentioned fact proves that $g(\tau,t-\tau)$ has compact support? We know that this function is non-zero if and only if $\tau \approx (-2)^k$ and $t - \tau \approx (-2)^l$ which implies $t \approx (-2)^k + (-2)^l$ but I don't see how the fact helps here. (4) Also I couldn't prove the mentioned fact. The reverse direction is obvious but the forward direction $(\Rightarrow)$ is not clear to me.

Comment: (1) Something like $\epsilon = 1/1000$ would be enough (even an overkill). The $\epsilon$ just need to be sufficiently small so that the fact about summing powers of $(-2)$ (the "quoted part" in the middle of the answer) can be transported to be about real numbers that are approximately powers of $(-2)$. Note that we are only using positive powers so that $|(-2)^k| \geq 1$.

Comment: (2) The only possibility that the Laplace transform converges is if the real part of $s$ vanishes. If you want to ensure disjoint support, just look at $\chi(t)$ and $e^t \chi(t)$, the latter can only have convergent Laplace transform when the real part of $s = -1$. (3/4) I'll edit the answer to include a bit more detail.

Comment: Thank you very much for the details. Could you explain why the Laplace transform converges only if the real part of $s$ vanishes? I don't see how we can prove that the imaginary part doesn't have any effect on the convergence of Laplace transform.

Comment: So how it can be proved that $\int \chi(t) \exp(-st) ~dt$ converges for no $s \in \mathbb{C}$? In the case that $s \in \mathbb{R}$ it's clear that integral diverges since we are summing rectangles which have increasing heights and exponential width but in the case of $s \in \mathbb{C}$ it's not clear to me how to prove that formally.

Comment: So it's possible that the Laplace transfom of $\chi(t)$ converges for some $s\in \mathbb{C}$? Maybe in that case ROCs aren't disjoint anymore.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it a bit more: the Laplace transform obviously cannot converge for real part of $s$ that is non-zero. The integral has the explicit form $$ \sum \frac{\exp(-s ((-2)^k - \epsilon))- \exp(-s ((-2)^k + \epsilon))}{s} = \left( \sum \frac{\exp(-s (-2)^k)}{s}\right) \left( \exp(s\epsilon) - \exp(-s\epsilon) \right)$$ When $s$ has non-zero real part, the quantity $\exp(-s (-2)^k) + \exp(-s (-2)^{k+1})$ has larger modulus then the sum of the first $k-1$ entries. So the integral cannot converge.

Comment: I see, indeed the numerical approximation shows that the summation $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \exp(-s(-2)^k)$$diverges very fast when the real part of $s$ is non-zero but the problem is that the numerical approximation of summation suggests the Laplace transform convergences for $s = ai$ and $|a| \lt 1$ (I couldn't test the case $|a| \ge 1$ because Mathematica returns "Overflow occurred in computation"). So we don't have $\text{ROC}_1 \cap \text{ROC}_2 = \emptyset$ and, consequently, the counterexample doesn't work.

Comment: @S.H.W. Once you can restrict the ROC to be subsets of the imaginary axis, you can shift it by replacing one copy of $\chi$ by $e^t\chi(t)$ as I [suggested in my earlier comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463154/necessary-conditions-for-convergence-of-convolution/463341?noredirect=1#comment1203194_463341).

Comment: @S.H.W in fact the integral diverges for all complex $s$ too. I edited the answer to include the short proof.

Comment: I see, thank you. Few days ago, I asked about the convergence of that series in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4860482/convergence-of-summation-of-complex-exponentials-with-alternating-exponent) math.SE post. If you add your proof I can accept your answer and award the bounty.

Comment: In order to better understand your great answer, I've asked a [separate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4863287/proving-a-function-has-a-compact-support) in math.SE. I would appreciate your help if you could take a look at it.